# Adding components of formula (net vs. gross)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to add the components of a formula across a range.  We have one section that shows the net cash flows for specific items, and multiple specific items.

For example `=8+9-5` shows "12" across multiple cells.  If the values weren't netted at a cell level, it would be easy to use a `SUMIF` formula to only add the positive and negative cells, but since it is netted at the cell level, I am trying to dig into the underlying values and use the equivalent to the `SUMIF` formula but for all the underlying components.

For the example above, I am trying to get a summary cell for the range to say "+17", and one cell to show "-5".

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you really have the formula `=8+9-5` in a cell? With constants instead of cell references? If so, WHY???? If not, post what's really in the cell.

Comment: Yes, it uses constants in the cell, it is an old legacy summary spreadsheet with many areas to be improved, but without undertaking a larger process, it is undo-able.  So, in the short term, my question still stands.

Comment: Re-design the spreadsheet. The effort involved in extracting the components of a formula using constants, so they can be evaluated with conditional functions is immensely greater.

Comment: I am as curious as anything as to how it is done though.  No details necessary if you don't plan to spend the time explaining it, but painting with broad strokes would still be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overriding issue is how to access the formula string of another cell from the worksheet. There is no existing worksheet function that can do this. So, you're going to have to do one of two things to start: 1) use find-and-replace to change the content of the cells so that they no longer hold formulas but hold strings instead, or 2) use VBA to access the formula string of the cells.

(1) can be accomplished by selecting the cells you want to manipulate and then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open the Replace dialog. Search for `=` (assuming the only formulas you're interested in are like your example and do not include subsequent equal signs), and replace with nothing. This will change a cell with formula `=8+9-5` showing value 12 to a cell showing the string `8+9-5`.

(2) can be accomplished by accessing the cell property `.Formula`. For instance, to get the formula of cell A1, you would use a dirt-simple UDF something like this:

```
Public Function GetFormula(r as Range) as String
   GetFormula = r.Formula
End Function
```

Once you have these strings, by either method, you'll have to get clever with string manipulation functions, e.g., `FIND`, `LEN`, and `VALUE`, to extract the values you want. Since doing this would be both a waste of your time and mine, I'll refrain from doing this here.

Answer (score 1):

Add a sheet to your workbook; let's call it "Setup".

In A1 put `8`, in A2 put `9`, in A3 put `-5`. Copy across as many columns as that formula with constants exists across columns in your original sheet. (Depending on how the range is organised, you may need the setup sheet to use A1, B1, C1 and copy down instead. The idea is to create a range that matches the shape of the range on the original sheet. )

On the original sheet replace all formulas `=8+9-5` with `=Setup!A1+Setup!A2+Setup!A3`. This can be done with a Find&Replace operation that evaluates the formulas.

Now you can build conditional formulas on the Setup sheet instead of the hard-coded values in the original sheet.

```
=sumif(Setup!A1:A3,">0")

=sumif(Setup!A1:A3,"<0")
```

Comment: This is the re-design approach, creating a new sheet for it to reference, rather than doing the math on the constants.

Comment: Was your comment a question or a statement?

Comment: A little of both.

Comment: Yes, this is meant to be a suggestion what you could do to solve your problem with a workaround.